# Select record in self-hierarchy that falls into a date range

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given table like this:

```
RecordId CreatedDate ParentRecordId
   1     2012/05/10       NULL   
   2     2012/05/13       NULL   
   3     2012/05/20        1     
   4     2012/05/30        3
```

I need to find out Record that resides between created dates give Date and RecordId.

Couple examples:

> 1. If Given: RecordId=4 and Date=2012/05/15 I need to return Record with RecordId=1
> 2. if Given: RecordId=4 and Date=2012/05/25 I need to return Record with RecordId=3
> 3. If Given: RecordId=2 and Date=2012/06/10 I need to return Record with RecordId=2
> 4. If Given: RecordId=2 and Date=2012/01/01 I need to return NULL
> 5. If Given: RecordId=1 and Date=2012/06/01 I need to return Record with RecordId=4

I think this will have to be a complex set of joins and calculations, I've been struggling for couple hours without any success.
Here's the mockup of a method I need to implement:

```
public Record GetRecord(int RecordId, DateTime Date)
{
  var query = ???
  return query;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved by recursion, for example:

```
public Record GetRecord(int RecordId, DateTime Date)
{
  var r = records.firstOrDefault(record => record.Id == RecordId && record.Date < Date)

  if(r != null && r.ParentId != null)
    return GetRecord(r.ParentId, Date)  // Get the parent, if existing..
  else
    return r;                           // Return the matching record
}
```

Not sure if I covered all of your logic, but you should be able to work from the above code :)

Comment: @user194076 If my answer answered your question please mark it as such :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I actually got the idea from your code, the final code is a bit different, but thanks a lot!